# Ошибка при запуске виртуального устройства Genymotion

Tags: genymotion

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь запустить виртальное устройство в Genymotion, но возникает ошибка, вот логи:

```
июн 22 03:12:37 [Genymotion] [Warning] Unable to load translations. Falling back to english
июн 22 03:12:37 [Genymotion] [Warning] ****  STARTING GENYMOTION  ****
июн 22 03:12:37 [Genymotion] [Warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion 2.5.0
июн 22 03:12:37 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LaunchpadApp] Started with ("./genymotion")
июн 22 03:12:37 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting: "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"
июн 22 03:12:37 [Genymotion] [Debug] Getting currently authenticated user from  local cache
июн 22 03:12:37 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] done
июн 22 03:12:37 [Genymotion] [Debug] [getGenymotionLastVersion] New version ( "2.5.0" ) available here: "http://files2.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-2.5.0/genymotion-2.5.0_x64.bin"
июн 22 03:12:37 [Genymotion] [Debug] Genymotion is up to date
июн 22 03:12:37 [Genymotion] [Debug] [login] Trying to authenticate  "dasanonim@gmail.com"
июн 22 03:12:37 [Genymotion] [Debug] Trying to logout user
июн 22 03:12:37 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting: "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/"
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] done
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] [login] Login process result: 1
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] [login] User authenticated: "dasanonim@gmail.com"
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] Loading "vboxmanage" plugin
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] Plugin "vboxmanage" loaded
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] Chipset: "GenuineIntel"
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] CPUID 0x1 (Intel): ECX= "dbae3bf"
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] Path: "VBoxManage"
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostinfo") returns 0
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online physical CPU number: 2
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online virtual CPU number: 2
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max CPU number: 4
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max memory size: 5867
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] Checking status of interface "vboxnet0" "192.168.56.1"
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] "vboxnet0" seems to be down
июн 22 03:12:38 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "dhcpservers") returns 0
июн 22 03:12:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "create") returns 0
июн 22 03:12:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] Host only adapter created with success: "vboxnet1"
июн 22 03:12:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0
июн 22 03:12:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "ipconfig", "vboxnet1", "--ip", "192.168.57.1", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0") returns 0
июн 22 03:12:39 [Genymotion] [Error] VBoxManage ("dhcpserver", "remove", "--ifname", "vboxnet1") returns 2
июн 22 03:12:39 [Genymotion] [Error] Output command: "VBoxManage: error: DHCP server does not exist"
июн 22 03:12:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("dhcpserver", "add", "--ifname", "vboxnet1", "--ip", "192.168.57.100", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0", "--lowerip", "192.168.57.101", "--upperip$
июн 22 03:12:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] DHCP server for adapter "vboxnet1" created with success
июн 22 03:12:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("--version") returns 0
июн 22 03:12:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] VM engine version: "4.3.10_Ubuntur93012"
июн 22 03:12:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] VMX/SVM CPU availability: true
июн 22 03:12:39 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("--version") returns 0
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас при запуске GenyMotion проваливается связь с Virtual Box на котором собственно и развернут GenyMotion. Проще говоря у вас не запущен сервис `VBoxMamage`

Comment: Как его запустить? Пробовал запустить комманду в терминале: `VBoxMamage`, но система ее не знает. Пробовал переустановить VB, также без результата.